# zmq crash in the second loop when recv message of an encoded image through tcp

Tags: c++, zeromq

In the following example with the usage of zmq and opencv encode and decode, the server crash in the recv() function after it shows the first image received. I would like to know if anyone know the reason why the code crashes.

The crash message is "C++ exception: zmq::error_t at memory location."

server

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
int main()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind("tcp://*:6666");
    while (true)
    {
        //  receive message
        std::string msgStr;
        {
            zmq::message_t message;
            socket.recv(&message);
            msgStr = std::string((char*)message.data(), message.size());
        }
        //  unserialize to cv::mat
        cv::Mat loaded_data;
        {
            std::vector<uchar> data(msgStr.begin(), msgStr.end());
            loaded_data = cv::imdecode(data, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        }
        //  show cv::mat
        {
            std::cout << "waiting for your key press on the image." << "\n";
            cv::imshow("load", loaded_data);
            cv::waitKey(0);
        }
    }
    socket.close();
    return 0;
}
```

client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
int main()
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t sock(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    sock.connect("tcp://localhost:6666");
    std::string data;
    {
        cv::Mat Imgdata = cv::imread("wall.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        std::vector<uchar> data_encode;
        cv::imencode(".jpg", Imgdata, data_encode);
        data = std::string(data_encode.begin(), data_encode.end());
    }
    // send
    {
        zmq::message_t message(data.size());
        memcpy(message.data(), data.c_str(), data.size());
        sock.send(message);
    }
    sock.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you use a std::string to send the message ? You could directly use `std::vector<uint8_t> vector.data() ` . Avoid unnecessary copy

Comment: Regarding your question : it is a bad idea to disregard the return of the recv function. Try doing this : `if(socket.recv(...)) { // Process image } `

Comment: You are also using REQUEST / REPLY socket but your reply socket never answer the REQ socket

Comment: @Clonk You are correct that I have missed the reply. Many Thanks.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer if that solves your problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not disregard the return of the recv function.
Doing `if(socket.recv(...)) { // Process image }` will avoid executing code in case of an error during reception.

You are using REQ / REP Socket. 
This is a synchrone protocol. 
REQ can initially send a message and are in blocked stated as long as they don't have a reply to the request.
REP can initially receive a message and are in blocked stated as long as they haven't answered the request.

Either reply to the REQ socket after receiving the first image or use another pattern : ZMQ_PAIR, PUSH / PULL, ROUTER / DEALER could all work in your case. [Read the documentation to learn about the different pattern](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket).

Also, you don't have to convert your image in a string. You can directly send `std::vector<uint8_t>`using zmq : you can access the underlying pointer using `std::vector::data()` and `memcpy(message.data(), vector.data(), vector.size())`.